# MDriven | Error on UpdateDatabase, stack trace error below

Tags: mdriven

Please note the below stack trace error we receive at times while updating the database.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeEndService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Eco.Wcf.Common.IPersistenceMapperWCF.EndUpdate(IAsyncResult result)
   at Eco.Wcf.Common.WFCWrapProxyAndActSync.Update(Datablock datablock, UpdatePrecondition precondition, IdTranslationList& translationList, Int32& version, SyncVersion& syncVersion, UpdateResult& result)
   at Eco.Wcf.Client.PersistenceMapperWCFClient.Eco.Persistence.IPersistenceMapper.Update(Datablock datablock, UpdatePrecondition precondition, IdTranslationList& translationList, Int32& version, SyncVersion& syncVersion, UpdateResult& result)
   at Eco.Framework.DefaultImpl.PersistenceHandlerImpl.InternalUpdateDatabaseWithLocators(ICollection`1 LocatorsToUpdate, List`1 seensysasyncticketsthatpointsatnewobjects)
   at Eco.Framework.DefaultImpl.PersistenceHandlerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<UpdateDatabaseWithList>b__0()
   at Eco.Services.Impl.AsyncSupportServiceImpl.WrapTaskInStandardExceptionHandling(Action task)
   at Eco.Services.Impl.AsyncSupportServiceImpl.PerformTaskNowIfInAsyncThread(Action task)
   at Eco.Framework.DefaultImpl.PersistenceHandlerImpl.UpdateDatabaseWithList(ICollection`1 LocatorsToUpdate)
   at Eco.Services.Impl.PersistenceServiceImpl.UpdateDatabaseWithList[T](IEnumerable`1 list)
   at RetroNET.SyncManager.ApplySyncPackage(XDocument syncPackage, ISiteSyncServiceProvider es)
```

Could you please assist further?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace show an update operation failing - if this update is being executed towards a persistence mapper that currently is in an evolve process it is somewhat expected - if the schema change mid update there is no guarantee the update operation address things that exists after the evolve.

The current preferred way to communicate with the PeristenceMapper is over WebAPI as described here https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/WebApi
The Above stack trace seems to show you use the old WCF (WindowsCommunicationFoundation) way - but that is not important for the error I think.

Comment: Hi Hans, will follow your suggestions and update accordingly and will keep a watch incase this error pops up again.